# Is there a shorter way of saying 'people who live or are planning to live in (this country)'?

Tags: word-choice

I'm building a forum for people who live or are planning to live in Taiwan. It is mainly for foreigners to ask questions or start topics.

I was wondering is there is a shorter way of saying that (or it is just OK as it is right now?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use *current* (or *present*) *and prospective residents*. A prospective resident is a person who is considering becoming a resident in the future, but may or may not yet be certain about it.

Answer (score 3):

I’d be more likely to write *residents and prospective residents of Taiwan*, but what you have is also perfectly acceptable.

**Added:** As is Jon Purdy’s version, *current/present and prospective residents*, which has the virtue of being even shorter than my suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're starting a forum for expats in Taiwan. An expat (expatriate) is any foreign resident of a given country. It is a popular term for describing foreigners in Asia and elsewhere (including Taiwan, where I taught English years ago), and has no negative connotations. So you could say "expats and prospective expats," although I would just use expats, since prospective expats will still join your forum.

I suppose if someone gets Taiwanese citizenship, he is technically no longer an expat, but that seems a bit of a quibble, as such a person would still have strong associations with the culture of his original country.